# Gyro for Arduino

Tags: arduino, gyro

[Background]

I've assembled a quadrocopter and now I'm going to design a flight controller for it, using Arduino. I can not use any of flight controllers, which you can buy in the store, only hand-made. So, I really want to find the **EASIEST** hardware solution for it.

[/Background]

The only gyro I've found at local stores is digital `LSM303 DLH`. But I doubt hardly about one thing. At my local store it's being sold in [QFN package](http://elcodis.com/photos/38/65/386549/lsm303dlh.jpg). I've found this gyro being sold with a [breakout board](http://bildr.org/2011/06/l3g4200d-arduino/). I don't get it, why are there some other components on it? Can I just connect wires from the chip to arduino and read the values?

Or maybe you can advice some other gyro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The components on the L3G4200D breakout board you linked to are:

- 2 I<sup>2</sup>C pullup resistors (which you need for I<sup>2</sup>C)
- 2 decoupling capacitors, which you need for providing proper power to the chip
- a PLL low-pass filter, which is required for this gyro

So this breakout board already is the minimal solution you can get for this chip.

And since most (if not all) gyros you can get are in leadless packages with (typically) a 0.5mm pitch, you don't really want to solder wires to them manually. Using a breakout board is way better, and you get mounting holes for free :)
(Dave Jones demonstrated in this [EEVBlog episode](http://www.eevblog.com/2011/06/21/eevblog-181-dead-bug-prototype-soldering/) how to do this with an accelerometer, if you really want to)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to hook a LSM303DLH up directly with the arduino without any parts added, however you will most likely notice it to be a lot harder. Take a look at the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00260288.pdf) for a explanation of what these things on the board in the picture does, or just start at page 20 and look at the application notes there. You might notice the stamp over the data sheet that the LSM303DLH is a obsolete product, and you might wish to consider this as well.

You would be able to build the circuit on the board yourself and get the same sort of results based on the details in the data sheet.

Comment: If it's obsolete, can you advice some better gyro than LSM303DLH?

Comment: @Kolyunya: There are tons of gyro choices out there; you can find some with breakout boards for example on [this page](http://www.sparkfun.com/categories/85).